# Crop Detected Face in Android

Tags: android, crop, face-detection

**What I Need:**

To Crop out the only exact face from Image.

**What I Have Done:**

https://github.com/blundell/FaceDetectionTutorialWithPreview

With This way or with

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision

Both way I am getting Face Detected. But I am unable to crop the detected Face.

I tried with

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        RectF sourceRect = null , destRect = null;

        for (Camera.Face f : mFaces) {

            // Draws a circle at the position of the detected face, with the face's track id below.
            float x = translateX(f.rect.centerX() + f.rect.width() / 2);
            float y = translateY(f.rect.centerY() + f.rect.height() / 2);
            //canvas.drawCircle(x, y, FACE_POSITION_RADIUS, mFacePositionPaint);
            //  canvas.drawText("id: " + mFaceId, x + ID_X_OFFSET, y + ID_Y_OFFSET, mIdPaint);
            // canvas.drawText("happiness: " + String.format("%.2f", face.getIsSmilingProbability()), x - ID_X_OFFSET, y - ID_Y_OFFSET, mIdPaint);
            // canvas.drawText("right eye: " + String.format("%.2f", face.getIsRightEyeOpenProbability()), x + ID_X_OFFSET * 2, y + ID_Y_OFFSET * 2, mIdPaint);
            //canvas.drawText("left eye: " + String.format("%.2f", face.getIsLeftEyeOpenProbability()), x - ID_X_OFFSET*2, y - ID_Y_OFFSET*2, mIdPaint);

            // Draws a bounding box around the face.
            float xOffset = scaleX(f.rect.width() / 2.0f);
            float yOffset = scaleY(f.rect.height() / 2.0f);
            float left = x - xOffset;
            float top = y - yOffset;
            float right = x + xOffset;
            float bottom = y + yOffset;

            sourceRect = new RectF(0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
            destRect = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);

            Log.v("Margins: ","top: "+top+"\n"+"left: "+left+"\n"+"right: "+right+"\n"+"bottom: "+bottom+"\n");

        }


        matrix.setRectToRect(sourceRect, destRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);

        matrix.postRotate(angle);

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
                matrix, true);
```

The same code working for drawing it for canvas but while cropping its not working.

For Now, I am taking pictures of the whole view. Just need the way how to crop from that image like below.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Guys Thanks for your time. I successfully cropped the images out of source bitmap using opencv.

Link i followed
[OpenCv Code](https://github.com/abhn/marvel/blob/master/facerecognition/src/main/java/cultoftheunicorn/marvel/Training.java)

Code To Save cropped Face.

```
if ((facesArray.length>0) && (faceState==SEARCHING))
        {
            Mat m=new Mat();
            m=mGray.submat(facesArray[0]);
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(m.width(),m.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


            Utils.matToBitmap(m, mBitmap);
            Message msg = new Message();
            String textTochange = "IMG";
            msg.obj = textTochange;
            //mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

            textTochange = fr.predict(m);
            mLikely=fr.getProb();
            msg = new Message();
            msg.obj = textTochange;
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);


            //for saving added below code

            bmpToSave = Bitmap.createBitmap(m.width(), m.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Utils.matToBitmap(m,bmpToSave);
            bmpToSave= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpToSave, 128, 128, false);


            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();

            Log.v("path: ", "" + pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
            Log.v("path: ", "" + pictureFile.getPath());



            ///storage/emulated/0/ABC/MI_04092018_1218.jpg

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                bmpToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
                fos.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("FD", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("FD", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
```

Credit goes to [MIT](https://github.com/abhn/marvel)

Answer (score 0):

You can crop your image with the `Bitmap.createBitmap()` method. Instead of passing whole image (0, 0, width, height), you can specified the rectangle you want (start X, start Y, width, height)

Comment: can u please elaborate it  (start X, start Y, width, height)  with an example?

Comment: `destRect = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);` it is the size of the cropped image you want, right ? So, startX=left, startY=top, width=right-top and height=top-bottom

Comment: no brother not working. can u suggest any other solution. for me left and top is coming sometimes in -ve value.. that's why.

Comment: I'm sorry, it is the way to crop... If you've got negative values, it means that bounds are outside the image ? Or can you take absolute values then ? https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-use-bitmapcreatebitmap-crop-image-homan-huang

Comment: Can u tell me one thing here i am getting these values as below for drawing rect arround face detected:                    
    top: 9.6910095
    left: 492.4464
    right: 973.1604
    bottom: 460.36035
    height: 400.59497
    width: 320.47598                                                                                                  The Same i am trying to crop but its not getting it.

Comment: How do you compute these values ?

Comment: as it is in my question .

Comment: hmmm, strange...is the "bounding box around the face" correct ?

Comment: yes. Anyway finally i did it with opencv Thanks for help

Comment: posted my answer. Please accept it if u found its correct.